# Elasticsearch indexing performance: throttle merging

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

We are importing data to elasticsearch cluster in few indices, around ~10gb each.
At the same time, we care about search on existing indices, few of them are small-~100mb, few of them are big-~10gb.

In order to optimize indexing, we:
 - use `bulk` api with optimized bulk size;
 - set refresh interval to `-1`;
 - set replication factor to `0`;

Now, we are trying to understand how merge throttling can help.
How search and segment merging are related, if search only against existing indices?

According to this [article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html#segments-and-merging), we can disable merge throttling.
- Does that mean merges will "eat" disks i/o?
- Does that mean merges won't happen at all and we have to `_forcemerge` manually, after indexing is done? Should be worried about max open file descriptors in such case?

According to these [article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/performance-indexing-2-0) and [pull request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/9243/files) we shouldn't touch merging settings at all.

Very confused here, any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to discussion [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-indexing-performance-throttle-merging/):

> Since ES 2.x, the IO throttling is handled automatically by Lucene,
>   meaning it starts at 20 MB/sec throttle on writing bytes to the merged
>   segment. It then increases that rate when merges fall behind, and
>   decreases it otherwise. This means the merges, over time, only soak up
>   as much IO bandwidth as is needed to keep up with your rate of
>   indexing.